# Changing the default command of base docker images

Tags: docker

I downloaded the ubuntu base image from the docker hub. Now I am trying to build a new image based on the ubuntu image. However, I want the default command for the ubuntu image to be "/bin/bash -c" instead of "/bin/sh" so as when I use RUN in my Dockerfile, it accesses bash instead of sh. Notice I am talking about the default command of the same image, not the image I am trying to build.

Comment: You need to build your own container using a docker file. See the  ENTRYPOINT and CMD directives: https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder

Comment: I already did. I have a very simple Docerfile that changes the ENTRYPOINT of ubuntu
    FROM ubuntu
    ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]

However, when I build this image and run the following command
docker run ubuntu2 echo hi

it doesnt show anything. Further investigating this. It appears that echo hi is not passed as a string. When I put 'echo hi' instead, it works!

Answer (score 10):

maybe this can help:

`SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]`

Reference:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7281#issuecomment-389440503

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a default command in the `ubuntu` image. When you run

```
$ docker run ubuntu echo hi
hi
```

it runs `["/bin/echo", "hi"]`. You can verify that by running

```
$ docker run ubuntu set
2014/06/20 08:38:54 exec: "set": executable file not found in $PATH
```

`set` is built-in command in shell, but docker tries to run it as an external one.

If you want to change the default shell from dash to bash, you can create an image with the fixed symlink. Here's a dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

[EDIT]

I just realized what you're talking about. I don't know if you can change the default for `RUN` command, but you can explicitly use /bin/bash like this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c ...
```

Comment: `RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh` this is a terrible idea. ubuntu targets /bin/sh to dash for a reason. dash is a fully posix shell which is orders of magnitude faster than bash. linking /bin/sh to bash will drastically reduce your server's performance. cite: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: @xero, this is inside a docker container. I don't think it will have much impact, because normally you will not run any of the scripts in /etc in the container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "<command>"]`

Answer (score 0):

RUN chsh -s /bin/bash
Add this in you docker file and the complete commands mentioned below this line will be executed with bash