# getting error /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, nvm

I am trying to build docker and installing nvm

some code line

```
RUN curl   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash
    RUN source ~/.profile
```

curl run successfully but when running source, getting below error

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c source ~/.profile' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Going to hate to break it to you. But source not found means whatever it is trying to install from a specific directory, cannot be found. So are you sure you followed the tutorial you are following entirely and not missing something?

Comment: yes have paste this code from tutorial.. i want to install nvm so following this link       https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: Can you link to the source of the tutorial? Source not found is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: the tutorial says : After running the above command, you may receive output similar to the following:

Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm

Either do as the output suggests, and close and reopen your terminal session, or run the command.

Comment: here i am using docker file for. how can i open and close terminal of docker image. i am directly building docker file from my ubuntu terminal.

Comment: use `.` instead of `source`

Comment: To use source, you can change the shell to bash https://stackoverflow.com/a/68254128/664054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this answer

instead of installing nvm by `"source ~/.profile"`

i change it to

```
RUN curl   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash

ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION=4.5.0
RUN . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && nvm use default
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The default shell for the shell form can be changed using the SHELL
>   command.
>
> In the shell form you can use a \ (backslash) to continue a single RUN
>   instruction onto the next line. For example, consider these two lines:
>   RUN /bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc ;\ echo $HOME' Together they
>   are equivalent to this single line: RUN /bin/bash -c 'source
>   $HOME/.bashrc ; echo $HOME'
>
> Note: To use a different shell, other than ‘/bin/sh’, use the exec
>   form passing in the desired shell. For example, RUN ["/bin/bash",
>   "-c", "echo hello"]

You could try:

```
RUN curl   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash
# RUN source ~/.profile
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.profile"]
```

Comment: here i am getting same issue.

Comment: What happed at line ```RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.profile"]```?

Comment: The command '/bin/bash -c source ~/.profile' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: now again i am getting other error for --- RUN npm install---- also tried ---RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "npm install"]---

Comment: Look like you're trying to build a node.js application inside a Docker container? You might need to post the full source code or the source code link to review.