# How do I install a specific release of node and NPM on Laravel Sail?

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, npm, laravel-sail

My Dockerfile fails to build when I try to install a specific version of node and npm.
I followed the option 3 in this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04

But it causes an error on `RUN source ~/.bashrc` with error: `/bin/sh source not found`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.10
 
LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"
 
ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG NPM_VERSION
 
WORKDIR /var/www/html
 
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC
 
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
 
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
 
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash 
RUN source ~/.bashrc
RUN nvm install v$NODE_VERSION 
RUN npm install -g npm@$NPM_VERSION 
 
RUN update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0
 
RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0
 
RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail
 
COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container
 
EXPOSE 8000
 
ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                NODE_VERSION: '14.17.0'
                NPM_VERSION: '6.14.13'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

These are the versions I'm trying to install:

- npm - 6.14.3
- node - 14.17.0

Comment: `source` isn't a standard shell command, and in any case environment variables you set using `RUN .` or bash's `source` extension command won't persist into future shell commands.  Try directly installing the version of Node you need without a version manager like nvm, or even using a separate `node:14.17.0` container.  Also see [getting error /bin/sh: 1: source: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647417/getting-error-bin-sh-1-source-not-found) or [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker).